# Velero deployments failure - Unable to find Azure /credentials/cloud File

Tags: azure, kubernetes, backup, azure-aks

Deployment Logs::

> An error occurred: some backup storage locations are invalid: error
>   getting backup store for location "default": rpc error: code = Unknown
>   desc = error loading environment from AZURE_CREDENTIALS_FILE
>   (/credentials/cloud): open /credentials/cloud: no such file or
>   directory

Installed velero following https://velero.io/docs/v1.1.0/azure-config/

Installed velero with

```
velero install \
    --provider azure \
    --bucket $BLOB_CONTAINER \
    --secret-file ./credentials-velero \
```

Comment: its probably a stupid question, but did you create the file like the guide tells you to?

Comment: Apparently you are missing the credentials-velero file. Please follow [this](https://velero.io/docs/v1.1.0/azure-config/#create-azure-storage-account-and-blob-container) part of tutorial.

Comment: yes i completed that part of the tutorial as i can see
spec:
  config:
    resourceGroup: Cluster_Backups
    storageAccount: cluster
  objectStorage:
    bucket: devcluster
    prefix: ""
  provider: azure
status:
  lastSyncedTime: nullee my storage account and RG

Comment: Though i found out this https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/17457 but nobody else seem to have similar issue with AKS, so i may be missing something obvious here

Comment: as the error says cannot find the path of the file, changed my approach on specifying the required as [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/), and works now.

Comment: You can add an answer to show the solution to help other communities who are looking for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the error says cannot find the path of the file, changed my approach on specifying the required as environment secrets than specified in documents as [here](https://usekubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

env:
  - name: SECRET_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: mysecret
        key: username